# BASH rename .log to .LOG

Tags: bash

I am having a hard time understanding this. I have researched brace expansion and the `mv` command but for some reason it still isn't making sense to me. I am reading Unix and Linux system administration handbook and they use this as an example, but I'm not understanding the line:

```
mv $fname ${fname/.log/.LOG};
```

I realize it is moving the current `$fname` variable which is anything with .log but the `${fname/.log/.LOG};` is confusing me. I thought it was basically `mv` source destination... So why are there 2 /'s?  If someone could explain this to me in plain english I would be most appreciative!

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -type f -name '*.log' | grep -v .do-not-touch | while read fname;
do
mv $fname ${fname/.log/.LOG/};
done
```

Comment: read about bash parameter pattern expansion. Here is a good link http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Comment: I would anchor the extension: `${fname/%.log/.LOG}` although I would write: `mv "$fname" "${fname%.log}.LOG"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `mv` line should be interpreted as "Move `$fname` to `${fname/.log/.LOG}`". The `${var/pattern/string}` construct is one form of the Parameter Expansion called Pattern Substitution. It returns the variable's value with the first occurrence of the pattern replaced by the string. In other words, it replaces `.log` with `.LOG` in this case. Therefore, for each file, the line is something like

```
mv file.log file.LOG
```

Comment: Thank you!  That explanation clears things up  This part was very helpful ${var/pattern/string}  I didn't know that was even possible.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

As you said, $fname contains the original file name ending with ".log". The bash expression you see says: Take the contents of the variable $fname, find ".log" and replace it with ".LOG". The resulting line will move a file that ends with ".log" to a file with the same name, but having the ".log" replaced by ".LOG".

You might want to look at http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ or http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/abs-guide.pdf for the Advanced bash scripting guide.

Comment: thank you!  I think i understand now.  I am going to read those links that you sent me...I appreciate the help and quick responses!